# Eclipse - close without saving workspace

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, mount

Is there a way to close Eclipse without saving the workspace?

I work with a remote drive that, on occasion, I forget to mount before I open up Eclipse. This, ultimately, closes all of the open projects I have in the workspace on the drive since it cannot reach those source files. To fix it, I'd like to simply be able to close eclipse without saving the workspace, mount the drive, and reopen eclipse so if there's a better way to do this, I'm all ears.

As a sidenote, I cannot automatically mount the drive since it requires user credentials to access so please don't suggest this.

Comment: You could write a Linux script that would stop you from opening Eclipse unless the remote drive is mounted.

Comment: Good point, @GilbertLeBlanc. I feel kind of stupid for not thinking of it myself. I'll give that a shot since Eclipse doesn't seem to be able to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a way out of this. Once the project is closed in the workspace, that state is persisted to disk, so there is no notion of "saving the workspace" later that's going to help you.